# Subsetting a data frame based on values specified in another dataset

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

I have a data frame similar to `DataSetA` created below. Observations represent measurements of the same 3 variables taken across the length of each individual. Within individuals (A,B,C,etc.), every observation is an equal distance away from the previous observation. To clarify, in the real data, the length of each individual is different. Therefore the number of indices is the same for each variable (`Var1`, `Var2`, `Var3`) within each individual, but not between each individual (`Individual A` may have 50 observations, but `Individual B` may have 70).

I am interested in comparing data of equivalent lengths *between individuals* that start at different locations within **each individual**. So I empirically detect a single "point of interest" (a single index) within each individual, and want gather that point and the 9 previous points leading up to it for comparison between individuals.

I need to subset the data in such a way that I end up with a new data frame containing those ten observations for each individual in the same format as the original data frame. In the past I have accomplished this using the filter and slice functions through Tidyverse (shown below) on each individual, and combining them into the new dataframe using rbind. However doing it this way requires strenuous amounts of repetition (and time) in my code, and my dataset is growing.

I would like to create a separate object that has one row and two columns for each individual that contains the individuals ID and the corresponding index of their "point of interest". Essentially I want to say; "if the `id` in data set `A` matches the `id` in data set `B`, the number beside that `ID` in dataset `B` is the index of the row I want `R` to start at in dataset `A` (the point of interest), and return that row and the nine rows before it in a new data frame".

I am not sure if for loops are the appropriate way to do this, or if there is something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```r
Individuals <- rep(c("A","B","C"), each = 50)

Var1 <- rnorm(50)
Var2 <- rnorm(50)
Var3 <- rnorm(50)

DataSetA <- cbind(Individuals, Var1, Var2, Var3)
DataSetA <- data.frame(DataSetA)

#How I usually filter to achieve what I want:
#The point of interest for Individual A is the 32nd observation taken on
#Individual A, so I need observations 23:32
A <-
  DataSetA%>%
  filter(Individuals == A)%>%
  slice(23:32)
#The point of interest for Individual B is the 35th observation taken on
#Individual B, so I need observations 26:35
#note that this is the 35th observation for that individual (not the 35th observation of the data set)
B <-
  DataSetA%>%
  filter(Individuals == B)%>%
  slice(26:35)
#The point of interest for Individual C is the 16th observation taken on
#Individual B, so I need observations 7:16
C <- 
  DataSetA%>%
  filter(Individuals == C)%>%
  slice(7:16)
#I then have to combine them using rbind
ExtractedData <- rbind(A,B,C)

#Below creates what I would like to use as "dataset B" to tell R what number to start filtering at in DataSetA

Individuals <- c("A","B","C")
PointOfInterest <- c(32,35,16)
DataSetB <- data.frame(Individuals, PointOfInterest)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map2_df(DataSetB$Individuals, DataSetB$PointOfInterest, ~ 
       DataSetA %>%
           filter(Individuals == .x, row_number() > .y))
```

---

If we want to filter 9 rows including the one showed in 'PointOfInterest' in 'DatasetB'

```
 map2_df(DataSetB$Individuals, DataSetB$PointOfInterest, ~ 
       DataSetA %>%
       group_by(Individuals)%>%
       mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% #just to show the row number
            filter(Individuals == .x, between(row_number(), .y-9, .y)))
#   Individuals        Var1        Var2        Var3 rn
#1            A -0.50715002 -1.63196034  0.24824287 23
#2            A -0.50694324  0.99443347 -0.25148466 24
#3            A  0.26498877  1.59758547 -0.97999740 25
#4            A  0.59168174 -0.67593906  0.58904189 26
#5            A -0.28834071  0.50565228 -1.40489489 27
#6            A -0.52907038  0.86131470 -1.50978892 28
#7            A -0.17986538  0.74555059 -0.42154441 29
#8            A -0.93043770  0.94839988  1.28018362 30
#9            A -2.46745604 -0.27824127 -0.36406006 31
#10           A -0.05040743  1.13697037 -0.85254191 32
#11           B  0.08314367 -0.07045269 -0.02063172 51
#12           B  2.78494703 -0.75031916 -0.90366751 52
#13           B  0.59528232 -0.09401376  2.14675010 53
#14           B  0.07766635  0.41274946  0.52784216 54
```

Comment: I have never used map but I am playing around with this and it seems like it could work. How would I tell it to filter the point of interest minus 9 data points?

Comment: @Ryan Not clear about the condition.  Can you please update

Comment: @Ryan I couldn't find your comment.   I get a message about your comment, but while checking here, there is no comment

Comment: Apologies, let me attempt to clarify (and mark my code appropriately, I am new the site): If the `PointOfInterest` for individual A is the 32nd data point recorded for individual `A`. and the `PointOfInterest` for individual B is the 15th data point recorded for individual B, I need  `DataSetA %>% filter(Individuals==A)%>%slice(23:32)` and `DataSetA%>%filter(Individuals==B)%>%slice(6:15)` so that I have only the `PointOfInterest` and 9 data points before it for each individual.

Comment: @Ryan In that case, you  can change the `filter` step in my code to `filter(Individuals == .x,  between(row_number(), .y-9, .y))`

Comment: @Ryan Can you pleae check my update.  For the 'B', in `DataSetB`,  it is 54,  and in DataSetA, it starts from 51, therefore,  it is only subsetting 4 rows

Comment: I realized the points of interest included in my original example were obsolete with respect to the example data set, as you cannot be interested in the 54th observation of an individual if there are only 50 observations per individual. I edited the original code to clarify. When I try your update with this it only filters rows 23:32 for Individual A, I also need it to filter the 26th through 35th observation for Individual B, and the 7th through 16th observation taken on individual C.

Comment: One of the complications with this is I need the values in: `DataSetB$PointOfInterest` to refer to the nth observation taken on the respective individual. Instead of `mutate(rn = row_number())`, how could we make a row of "indices" numbered from 1:length individual (they are not all the same length in my real data set). thank you for your help and patience with this, I tried to move it to chat but It says I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @Ryan That is very easy too do i..e. `DataSetA %>%group_by(Individuals) %>% mutate(rn = row_number())`

Comment: Fantastic that worked!: `output<- map2_df(DataSetB$Individuals, DataSetB$PointOfInterest, ~
           DataSetA %>%
           group_by(Individuals)%>%
           mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% #just to show the row number
           filter(Individuals == .x, between(row_number(), .y-9, .y)))`